# Empty return from JQuery .contents()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the HTML using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = $("html").contents();
});
```

When I type `"html"` in chrome console I get `"[]"` what I think is the html variable is not loaded.

Doing the same thing in **other** web site, when I type `"html"` in chrome console i get

`[<head>​…​</head>​
,#text,<body class=​"page_color default_font  ext-webkit ext-chrome" id=​"ext-gen3" style>​…​</body>​]`

So, why there is that difference?
In both application I have the Jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by "application"?

Comment: Are you trying to load the content of an iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define it globally like this

```
var html;
$(document).ready(function () {
    html = $("html").contents();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring `html` in a function, it is not available at the global scope for you to access via the console.

If you need to see it in the console you could declare html as global.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.html = $("html").contents();
});
```